# How can I pull down vines with a tractor?

Tags: vines

I have invasive vines that are either well rooted in the ground, or sometimes grown up into the boughs of trees. I have a John Deere 1025r tractor and a heavy chain that can attach to the front of it, but it is not clear the best way to attach the chain to the vines to the chain so I can pull the vines out. Maybe lash it to the chain with a rope? Seems tedious.

Comment: Just curious - is the main goal to get them out of the trees, unroot them, or both?  Is there a preference if you can't do both?

Comment: Wonder if something like a [rope grip](https://www.wurtec.com/en/image/getthumbnail/15772?width=600&height=600&version=1&s=003) would work.

Comment: @JPhi1618 The goal is to transport every particle of vine DNA to the Romulan neutral zone.

Comment: Which vines? Which tree? I do not recommand a tractor, you will ruin your lawn. Ladder + scissors + a winter should be enough to hide them. Use a contact universal herbicide for the roots.

Comment: You can pull them down , BUT , what will the vines pull anything down ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Cut the vine off a few feet below the raised bucket.
2. Tie a loop or knot in the suspended vine end. Depending on your chain size and available hooks or eyes, knot the vine *through* the hardware. If your vine trunk is too large to knot, wrap your chain several times and hook it to itself to achieve a cinch effect.
3. Pull like a son of a gun, ideally directly downward. Vines are strong enough that you could pull a tree over or damage it by pulling sideways. Keep your eyes on the skies for impending disaster.

Of course, you could just cut them at the ground and let nature take its course. Brush herbicide onto the stumps to prevent regrowth.

Comment: The best herbicide to use is Triclopyr, brushed or drizzled on the stump as soon as possible after cutting it.

Comment: A typical tow chain has hooks on either end and makes an awesome brush removal tool. As stated above, wrap it around the trunk/vine/pile of brush several times and hook back on itself. The cinching effect is incredibly strong. I've even seen this method used to hoist a dead horse.